# Formatting SD card with 4096 bytes Allocation Size Unit

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, sd-card

I need to format an SD card to 4096 bytes Allocation Size Unit, but I'm not sure how. I know I need to type in a specific command into the terminal. Could anyone help me out by telling me what code I need to type in to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/325883/edit) your question to provide some context and more details? Often we get people asking questions because they've already decided on what they need to do, but sometimes there's also no context which means what they're wanting to do may not be the best option. For example, it'd be good to know if you need the SD card in a particular format to use wth a particular device? If you're following some sort of instructions, maybe including those in your question will help.

Comment: It may also be once we have the additional details that your question has previously been answered. For example, if you need to format the SD card in the FAT format, then this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43979/format-sd-card-with-fat-and-custom-file-allocation-unit-size?rq=1) may already have your answer.

Comment: I saw that comment, and I need to do it in FAT-32, but I'm not sure how to edit the code to the 4096 that I need. I'm attempting to do this at the suggestion of someone else to make it work for a project I'm trying to tackle, as right now I keep getting errors saying that the SD card isn't being read. I'm not sure if this'll fix it, but it worked for them after they received the same error, so thought I'd give it a shot before getting a new card.